# Deep Learning model with Different data types in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I trying to make a classification model with Keras. My data contains some numeric features and some text features. By text features I mean comments or something similar. Numeric features will be category, age so on.

I want to pass the text feature to a Embedding layer and then to a LSTM layer. The numeric feature needed to be passed to a series of Dense Layers. After that both layers needed to be concatenated. After that a Dense Layer to make the output.

How can I implement this type of model in Keras.?

Or is there any other way to use both numeric features and text based features in the model at the same time.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly easy to implement such a network using keras functional API. 
suppose you have defined two sequential models to process your textual and numerical features, you can then merge the output and continue with more layers:

```
txt_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(n,))
txt_feat = text_network(txt_input)
num_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(m,))
num_feat = num_network(input2)
concatinated = keras.layers.Concatenate()([txt_feat, num_feat])

out = keras.layers.Dense(nodes)(concatinated)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=out)
```

you can also use other types of merge using any [merge layer](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) from keras.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Tensorflow and have the same question as OP. When you say 'defined two sequential models to process your textual and numerical features', how would I go about doing this? Or, if possible, is there any Github repo someone has made so I can see an example in action? Thanks.